# How to set sentences to variables NLTK

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I'm pretty new to using nltk, and have gotten stuck. I want to split a text file into its individual sentences and have each sentence set to a variable for later use. I have the first part taken care of:

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize

text1 = open('/Users/joshuablew/Documents/myCorpus/version1.txt').read()

sent_tokenize(text1)
```

This prints back each sentence separated:

`['Who was the 44th president of the United States?', 'Where does he live?', 'This is just a plain sentence.', 'As well as this one, just to break up the questions.', 'How many houses make up the United States Congress?', 'What are they called?', 'Again, another question breakpoint here.', 'Who is our current President?', 'Can he run for re-election?', 'Why or why not?']`

From here I don't know what to do in order to have these sentences automatically saved to variables.

Or, is it possible to have the index `text1[0] = 'Who was the 44th president of the United States?'`, and `text1[1] = 'Where does he live?'` and so on? Where each index of the text file is each individual sentence

Thanks for the help.

Comment: sent_tokenize tokenizes a paragraph into a list of sentences. `textList = sent_tokenize(text1)` should give you this list which can be referenced through index.

Answer (score -1):

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize

with open('1.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    sentences=myfile.read()

number_of_sentences = sent_tokenize(sentences)

print(len(number_of_sentences))

textList = sent_tokenize(sentences)

print(textList)
```